# not able to download file in my project directory using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

i am not able to download file in my Project directory how can i download that any one help me for this
below is my code

```
downloadlink.click();
String Resumedownloadpath="C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\cb-comAutomation\\src\\test\\resources\\Download"
Assert.assertTrue(isFileDownloaded(Resumedownloadpath,"new_resume_001 (1).docx"),"Failed to download Expected document");//this is verify using assert
public boolean isFileDownloaded(String Resumedownloadpath, String fileName){//this function is validation
        boolean flag = false;
        File dir = new File(Resumedownloadpath);
        File[] dir_contents = dir.listFiles();
            
        for (int i = 0; i < dir_contents.length; i++) {
            if (dir_contents[i].getName().equals(fileName))
                return flag=true;
                }

        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: try with `Thread.sleep(time in ms)`

Comment: file is downloaded but in local directory i want to download in project directory if i click downloadlink.click() file automatically download in local directory i give path for project directory also but file not download in folder which i gave that path

Comment: Where and how did you "give path for project directory"?

Comment: Workaround would be to move that file to your appropriate location

Comment: i want move that file in this path-\\src\\test\\resources\\Download

Answer (score 0):

before starting browser, we need to set default download path, for example

```
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 prefs.put("download.default_directory",  System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator + "externalFiles" + File.separator + "downloadFiles");
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
 ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

so that files will be downloaded to specified folder.